# How does one filter an array of objects by each object item's property name?

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I'm kinda new to coding so sorry if I may sound dumb. This is my question:
I have an array of objects and wanted to filter it by the start of the object key.

```
[{
  a_1: 356
}, {
  a_2: 348
}, {
  b_1: 621
}, {
  c_9: 311
}, {
  b_8: 123
}, {
  a_8: 787
}]
```

The result should be like this, so only the objects with the key that starts with "a" pass the filter:

```
[{
  a_1: 356
}, {
  a_2: 348
}, {
  a_8: 787
}]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you have objects with different keys in the first place? Arrays of objects should generally all have the same keys so you can iterate and index predictably rather than having to call `Object.keys` all the time, which is a function that pretty much defeats the purpose of objects. You might want to reconsider your data structure. Do these objects only have one key in them? Please show the exact structure (this is pseudocode), along with your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: @Robson Thank you for responding so fast! sorry if I might haven't responded in the most practical way, I'm still a newbie on SO. Yes, I'm using js!

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for responding so fast! sorry if I might haven't responded in the most practical way, I'm still a newbie on SO. I'm fetching an API from a minecraft server (hypixel). There's this mode where you give weekly "cookies" to players as a reward of their builds. The API is full of stuff along with the "given_cookies_[number]" objects, where the [number] is the week number. (ex:  given_cookies_105126). I just have to erase everything and keep the objects that start with "given_cookies", then I can figure out the rest by myself. Edit: grammar mistakes

Comment: You can/should [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68885538/edit) to fix mistakes and show the exact input/output structures -- it's really hard to tell what it is based on a written description. Thanks. If the API response is strange, you might want to transform it before operating on it further. When there are `"foo_[number]": val`, that's best off as an array, `"foo": [val, ...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a helper function to behave like array.filter and make different implementations for you specific needs...

I hope you find it helpul

```js
let testCase1 ={
    a_1: 356, 
    a_2: 348, 
    b_1: 621, 
    c_9: 311, 
    b_8: 123, 
    a_8: 787,
}
 const testCase2=  [
    {
        a_1: 356,
        x:"something"
    }, 
    {
        a_2: 348,
        x:"something"
    },
    {
        b_1: 621,
        x:"something"
    },
    {
        c_9: 311,
        x:"something"
    },
    {
        b_8: 123,
        x:"something"
    },
    {
        a_8: 787,
        x:"something"
    }
]

// array filter like function
const objectFilter=(obj,check = (key,value)=>true )=>{
    const res = Object.keys(obj)
        .filter(key => check(key,obj[key]))
        .reduce((acc,current)=>({...acc,...{[current]:obj[current]}}),{})
        
    if(Object.keys(res).length > 0){
        return res
    }
}

// return an array with new objects containing only the filtered keys
const objectArrayFilter=(arr, check = (key,value)=>true)=>{
    return arr.map(item=>objectFilter(item,check)).filter(item=>item)
}

// return array with the original objects who contains the checked key pairs values
const objectArrayContains=(arr, check = (key,value)=>true)=>{
    return arr.filter(item=>objectFilter(item,check))
}

// object testing
function check(key,value){
    return key.startsWith("a") 
}

console.log(objectFilter(testCase1,check)) 
// output: { a_1: 356, a_2: 348 }}

console.log(objectArrayContains(testCase2,check)) 
//output: [  { a_1: 356, x: 'something' }, { a_2: 348, x: 'something' }, { a_8: 787, x: 'something' }  ]

console.log(objectArrayFilter(testCase2,check))
// output: [ { a_1: 356 }, { a_2: 348 }, { a_8: 787 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if your question has been solved or not.

Here is the code:

```
let objects ={
a_1: 356, 
a_2: 348, 
b_1: 621, 
c_9: 311, 
b_8: 123, 
}
console.log(Object.keys(objects).filter(check))
// return a_1,a_2;
function check(str){
   return str.startsWith("a") 
}
```

Comment: nope, the OP did state ... *"I have an array of objects ..."*

Answer (score 0):

The provided approach does [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) an array by looking at an object's/item's 1st key ... [`Object.keys(item)[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ... whether it [`startWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) the OP's required character `'a'` ...

```js
console.log(
  [{
    a_1: 356
  }, {
    a_2: 348
  }, {
    b_1: 621
  }, {
    c_9: 311
  }, {
    b_8: 123
  }, {
    a_8: 787

  }].filter(item => Object.keys(item)[0].startsWith('a'))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```